# Formulário de update para de funcionar ao implementar Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Este é o Ajax que eu quero implementar. Quando o formulário é submetido, exibe um GIF para mostrar que está carregando, e então dependendo do resultado, um alerta aparece com uma mensagem escrita por `json_encode`, e some.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#loading").fadeIn();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Operations.php",
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            showAlert("result-success", data.msg);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            showAlert("result-error", "Ocorreu um erro ao continuar");
        }
    });
});
```

Abaixo, o arquivo `Operations.php` recebe por `POST` o nome da classe e o id através de dois `hidden`, executa uma operação dependendo do formulário e por fim manda por JSON um resultado e uma mensagem, que será exibida pelo alerta criado pelo Ajax

```
<?php

$class = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "class");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id");

@require_once "../../php/Connection.php";
@require_once "../../php/ServiceDatabase.php";
@require_once "../../php/" . $class . ".php";

$Operation = new ServiceDatabase($connection, new $class);

switch ($_REQUEST["submit"]) {
    case "insert":
        $Operation->setPostVariables();

        if ($Operation->insert()) {
            $res = "success";
            $msg = "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
        }

        break;
    case "update":
        $Operation->setPostVariables();

        if ($Operation->update($id)) {
            $res = "success";
            $msg = "Dados atualizados com sucesso";
        }

        break;
    case "delete":
        if ($Operation->delete($id)) {
            $res = "success";
            $msg = "Dados apagados com sucesso";
        }

        break;
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "res" => $res,
    "msg" => $msg
));
```

Por fim, o formulário. Quando submetido, manda os valores atribuídos aos `hidden`, e também o valor do `button`, que fará com que uma ação seja executada.

```
<?php
session_start();

$class = ucfirst(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "t"));
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "i");

require_once "../../php/" . $class . ".php";

$Table = new ServiceDatabase($connection, new $class);
?>

<form id="form" class="center-block" action="Operations.php" method="post">
    <h3>Alterar - <small><?php echo $class ?></small></h3>

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $class ?>" name="class"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id"/>

    <?php echo $Table->generateAdminTables($id); ?>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-update">Atualizar</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete fright">Apagar</button>
</form>
```

**O Problema**

O Ajax executa e mostra o alerta ao cair no `success`, mas não exibe nenhuma mensagem. Fica `undefined`, e além disso, nenhuma operação do segundo arquivo é executada, apesar de mostrar sucesso. Se eu simplesmente comentar o Ajax, tudo funciona normalmente.

**Edição #1**

A pedido, o retorno de `data` é `Object { res: null, msg: null }`. Um outro detalhe que eu esqueci de comentar é que ao remover o Ajax e clicar no botão para atualizar os dados, no momento em que ele redireciona para o arquivo `Operations.php` para efetuar alguma operação, pode-se ver impresso na tela a informação do `json_encode`.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o que esta sendo retornado no `data` de `success: function(data)`? Utilize `console.log(data)` e atualize sua pergunta colocando esta informação por favor.

Comment: @Gerep Atualizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que `$_REQUEST` não funciona com Ajax. Que surpresa.

Minha solução é: eu criei um novo `hidden` dentro dos formulários que recebe via jQuery o `value` do `button` clicado:

```
btnValue = "";
$("#form button").click(function() {
    btnValue = $(this).attr("value");
});
```

Logo antes do `$.ajax` eu atribuo ao `hidden` o valor do `button`

```
$(this).find("#action").attr("value", btnValue);
```

No `Operations.php`, um novo `$_POST` é recebido

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "action");
```

E no bloco `switch`, eu apenas checo o `$action`

```
switch ($action) {
    case "insert": ...
    case "update": ...
    case "delete": ...
}
```

Funcionou perfeitamente.